# Omit property of object defined in MSON

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, mson

How can I ommit property from defined MSON? I have defined one simple entity (object) using MSON:

```
# Data Structures

## Article (object)
Represents an article

## Properties
+ id: 1 (number, optional)
+ name: My first article (string)

## Articles [/articles]

### Get all articles [GET]

Get all articles available on this website.

+ Response 200 (application/json)
 + Attributes (array[Article])

### Create an article [POST]

Create new article.

+ Request (application/json)
    + Attributes (Article)
```

I'm using `Article` object in several api endpoints. The problem is that I don't want `id` to be specified when posting new article so I want to omit it in the documentation for `POST` method. Is it possible to include `Article` entity in all endpoints and say what fields I want to omit?

Comment: Isn't the optional specification on data structure enough?

Comment: It is not optional... You can't set it, because the database fills `id` using auto increment. Maybe you are correct, you can post it and I can ignore it but it is weird to see it in documentation and can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actually way how to do it.
You have two options:

- declare `id` with attribute `nullable`
- Declare `Article` without `id` and later inherit from `Article` and attach `id`.

```
# Data Structures

## Article (object)
+ name: My first article (string)

## ArticleInstance (Article)
+ id (number)

## Articles [/articles]

### Get all articles [GET]

Get all articles available on this website.

+ Response 200 (application/json)
 + Attributes (array[Article])

### Create an article [POST]

Create new article.

+ Request (application/json)
    + Attributes (Article)
```

Comment: Thanks. It does not add `id` property to inherited `Article` though. `Article` and `ArticleInstance` are same. [Here you can see full blueprint](https://gist.github.com/Northys/aec89a325e223d86674e4d78cb31378c). Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry, fields are added to the bottom of the entity. It works, thank you!